# Powershell: how to execute command for a path containing Unicode characters?

Tags: node.js, powershell, shell, command-line, command-line-interface

I'm trying to execute a command in Powershell 5.1, but it fails when the path contains Unicode characters.

For example:

```sh
(Get-Acl 'E:/test .txt').access
```

I'm running the command from Node.js:

```js
let childProcess = require('child_process')
let testProcess = childProcess.spawn('powershell', [])
testProcess.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8')

testProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data.toString())
})

testProcess.stdout.on('error', (error) => {
  console.log(error)
})

// This path is working, I get command output in the console:
// testProcess.stdin.write("(Get-Acl 'E:/test.txt').access\n");

// This path is not working. I get nothing in the console
testProcess.stdin.write("(Get-Acl 'E:/test .txt').access\n");
```

I cannot use Powershell 7 since I'm making a Node.js app that runs commands on the pre-installed Powershell

### Update

This method seems to work:

```
childProcess.spawn(
  'powershell', 
  ['-Command', '(Get-Acl "E:/test .txt").access']
)
```

Comment: Make sure the script containing the emoji character literal is Unicode-encoded (UTF16LE), Windows PowerShell will choke on the UTF-8 representation otherwise.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, while saving PowerShell scripts as UTF-16LE definitely works, so does UTF-8 _with BOM_, and since scripts generally mostly contain ASCII-range characters, the latter is preferable in terms of file size.

Comment: How do I set encoding with an argument? I tried adding `-encoding utf8` and  `-encoding UTF16LE` to the command, but it's not working either

Comment: @AlekseyHoffman `-Encoding Unicode`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen not working either: `testProcess.stdin.write("(Get-Acl 'E:/test .txt').access -Encoding Unicode\n")`

Comment: Do you need to provide the commands _via stdin_? If not, try passing the command string via the `-c` (`-Command`) CLI parameter.

Comment: `-Encoding` would only apply to file-creation cmdlets such as `Set-Content`. The PowerShell CLI uses the console's active code page (by default, the system's active OEM code page) to read input from stdin. To get it to interpret the stdin input as UTF-8, you'd have to set the console's code page to `65001` _before_ invoking `powershell.exe`.

Comment: @mklement0 thank you for the solution. Passing the command as an array of arguments with `-Command` seems to work: `childProcess.spawn('powershell', ['-Command', '(Get-Acl "E:/test .txt").access'])` I get the command output in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By **using *stdin* input to provide your command to `powershell.exe`**, the [Windows PowerShell CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), **you're implicitly relying on the system's active *OEM* code page**, because that is what the PowerShell CLI uses to decode input received via stdin.

- Unless you've explicitly opted into the [still-in-beta Windows 10 feature that allows setting both legacy code pages - ANSI and OEM - to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375), the **OEM code page is a fixed single-byte encoding limited to 256 characters that lacks support for most Unicode characters**, such as [Code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) on US-English systems.
- Additionally, **providing commands via stdin** (which can explicitly be requested with `-File -`) **unexpectedly makes PowerShell exhibit pseudo-interactive behavior, which interferes with command output.** See [GitHub issue #3223](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3223) and [GitHub issue #15331](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15331) for a discussion of this problematic behavior.

By contrast, **passing commands via the `-c` (`-Command`) CLI *parameter* fully supports Unicode**, irrespective of the active OEM code page, so it is a simple alternative that bypasses your original problem; borrowing from your own update to your question:

```
childProcess.spawn(
  'powershell', 
  ['-NoProfile', '-Command', '(Get-Acl "E:/test .txt").access']
)
```

Note that I've added `-NoProfile` in order to make the invocation more predictable / speed it up, as this option suppresses loading of the profile files that are usually only relevant for *interactive* use.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Do you think there's a way to make it work with `stdin.write` (my initial metod)? Can I encode the file path either with Node.js before sending the command, or with powershell itself before processing the command?

Comment: @AlekseyHoffman, I don't know if you've seen my update re the pseudo-interactive behavior that stdin command input exhibits. You can _somewhat_ mitigate that by reading from stdin via `-Command -` instead, but the question is: why do you need stdin input?

Comment: @AlekseyHoffman, if you _do_ need stdin input - so that you can feed multiple commands over time to a single `powershell.exe` process as a kind of pseudo-REPL - can I suggest you create a _new_ question that is focused specifically on that?

Comment: I'm using stdin.write because it's faster for my use case. It takes about 500 ms for Node to spawn a child process. So I figured I could create a single process during app loading and then re-use it

Comment: Thanks for your additional suggestions. `-noProfile` makes sense with the 2nd approach. There's 1 thing I found interesting about the unicode conversion, I noticed that when I copy paste this command: `(Get-Acl "E:/test .txt").access` into the powershell manually, it converts the unicode character into `??` and works just fine. So I'm wondering, is there way to utilize this to pre-process paths using powershell capabilities? Also I'm not sure what do you mean by "mitigate that by reading from stdin via -Command"?

Comment: @AlekseyHoffman, `-Command -` also makes PowerShell read from stdin, but without also outputting a _prompt string_, which is what piping commands to `powershell.exe` by default or with `-File -` does. Character encoding issues aside, `-Command -` therefore is what you want, but beware of command strings that span multiple lines, as they require _two trailing newlines_ in order to be recognized - the linked GitHub issues detail all of this.

Comment: @AlekseyHoffman: As for copying into the terminal: the `??` are just a _display_ problem: the selected _font_ doesn't support the character, but that doesn't affect functionality.

Comment: @AlekseyHoffman, as for solving the character-encoding issues with stdin input, so you can get away with launching a _single_ `powershell.exe` process for processing multiple commands over time: it would indeed make sense to ask a new question focused on that; feel free to notify me here once you have done so, and I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: P.S., @AlekseyHoffman: `-NoProfile` _generally_ makes sense (unless you explicitly _want_ profiles to be loaded), irrespective of whether you use stdin input or `-Command`, because - very unfortunately - PowerShell always loads profiles by default.