# Node.js + Powershell: how to encode Unicode characters when using stdin.write

Tags: node.js, powershell

This question is related to this issue: [Powershell: how to execute command for a path containing Unicode characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67576947/powershell-how-to-execute-command-for-a-path-containing-unicode-characters/67577536)

I have a Node.js app that spawns a single child process with Powershell 5.1, and then re-uses it to run different commands since it's faster than spawning a separate process.

#### Problem

The problem is, commands containing Unicode characters are failing silently.

#### Code

```js
let childProcess = require('child_process')
let testProcess = childProcess.spawn('powershell', [])
testProcess.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8')

testProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data.toString())
})

testProcess.stdout.on('error', (error) => {
  console.log(error)
})

// This path is working, I get command output in the console:
// testProcess.stdin.write("(Get-Acl 'E:/test.txt').access\n");

// This path is not working. I get nothing in the console
testProcess.stdin.write("(Get-Acl 'E:/test .txt').access\n");
```

### Edit #1

I've tried to encode the paths to UTF-8 on the Node.js side before sending the command to Powershell and then casting it to System.Char:

```js
const path = 'E:/test $([char]0x1f4da).txt'
const command = `Get-Acl $(${path}).access`
testProcess.stdin.write(`${command}\n`)
```

but I'm not sure how to do it properly. It seems like I'm not encoding it to the correct format. And it's not really a proper solution either, I just encoded the emoji to utf manually. I would probably need to convert the whole path to UTF-16 or something to ensure there's no unsupported characters in it:

```
"E:/test .txt".split("").reduce((hex,c) => hex += c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).padStart(4,"0"),"")
```

Not sure it would even work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
let childProcess = require('child_process')

let testProcess = childProcess.spawn(
  'chcp 65001 >NUL & powershell.exe -NonInteractive -NoProfile -Command -', 
  { shell: true }
)

testProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data.toString())
})

testProcess.stdout.on('error', (error) => {
  console.log(error)
})

testProcess.stdin.write("Get-Item '.txt'\n");
```

- While Node.js *itself* defaults to UTF-8, **console applications** spawned from it typically **use the system's active *OEM* code page**, such as [Code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) on US-English systems, which is typically a fixed single-byte limited to 256 characters that lacks support for most Unicode characters.

  - As an an aside: there's a [still-in-beta Windows 10 feature that allows setting both legacy code pages - ANSI and OEM - to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375), but doing so has far-reaching consequences.
- `powershell.exe`, the [Windows PowerShell CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) is no exception, so in order to make it interpret its stdin input as UTF-8, the OEM code page must explicitly set to the UTF-8 code page, `65001`, *before* `powershell.exe` is launched.
- Thus, `{ shell : true }` is used to ensure that `powershell.exe` is launched via `cmd.exe`, the default shell on Windows, which allows executing `chcp 65001` first, which performs the switch to the UTF-8 code page.

  - Note: This switch to UTF-8 as the OEM code page also affects subsequent calls to console applications in the same process.
- Additionally:

  - `-NonInteractive` is used to tell PowerShell that no user interactions are expected in the session, which notably prevents loading of the `PSReadLine` module used for command-line editing, which can cause problems with Unicode characters outside the BMP, i.e. characters with a code point higher than `0xFFFF` (such as ), which require *two* `[char]` instances in .NET.
  - `-NoProfile` prevents loading (dot-sourcing) of the PowerShell profile files, given that they're (a) typically only needed in *interactive* sessions and (b) their loading not only slows things down, but can have *side effects*.
  - `-Command -` tells PowerShell to read commands from stdin; while *omitting* this parameter *somewhat* behaves similarly, it is the equivalent of `-File -`, which exhibits *pseudo-interactive behavior*.

    - As an aside: Ultimately, *both* `-Command -` and (implied) `-File -` exhibit unexpected behaviors, as discussed in [GitHub issue #3223](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3223) and [GitHub issue #15331](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15331)

Comment: You seem to know shells pretty well. Do you enjoy tinkering with open-source projects? In a few days I'm going to publish my modern advanced file manager app on [my Github page](https://github.com/aleksey-hoffman). If you wish, when the app is published, take a look at the code, maybe optimize a few things here and there as you see fit. You might even enjoy using the app itself, it has many great features for creators and developers

Comment: Hey mate, as promised, here's the link to the app: https://github.com/aleksey-hoffman/sigma-file-manager

Comment: Thanks, @AlekseyHoffman - looks pretty impressive.

Comment: Thanks :) an update is coming out today, it will include some bug fixes and new features